# Adjective or noun for a personality trait of someone who is considerate of those weaker than themselves

Tags: adjectives, interpersonal-relations

I’m wondering if anyone can help me with a word that means a person who is considerate of the opinions of others particularly those weaker than them? I have in the back of my mind it begins with the letter P

Comment: Weaker? In what way?

Comment: "Weaker"?! Well, if that's how they fancy themselves and what they're doing, then the P word I'd use to describe that person is "patronizing."

Comment: Paediatrician? Punchbag? What's the angle?